# The server is not correctly configured (-12939)

Tags: iphone, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, media-player

Trying to play MP3 from server without first downloading the file locally. Callback for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification comes with this:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x7e1c980 {name = MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification; object = <ItemMediaPlayer: 0x7856740>; userInfo = {
    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 1;
    error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-12939 \"The server is not correctly configured.\" UserInfo=0x7e243d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The server is not correctly configured.}";
```

Now trying to figure out **what does error code -12939 actually mean**... Does MPMoviePlayerController expect that server must support **byte range requests**? Because this server does not (using nginx)!

To complicate things, this code **fails on iOS 4.0, but works on iOS 4.1**. Now thinking about dropping iOS 4.0 support, unless someone can propose a fix?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [AudioStream](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer), which allows you play a MP3 from a URL by streaming it.

The error could do with the fact that your server does not support "Range Requests".

Comment: The question was whether anyone knows what "-12939" error code means. Edited question to highlight that, sorry about confusion... AudioStream looks like an excellent project, but it's not an answer to my question (or I missed something?).

Comment: No it's not an answer directly, but could work as a replacement option.