# AVPlayerItem Error : Operation Stopped

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I want to play a youtube video with AVPlayer.

Here is my Code :

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(url:URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx")!))
player = AVPlayer(playerItem : playerItem)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
player.play()
```

The `AVPlayerItemStatus` passes to failed with this error :

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1702443e0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12939 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}
```

Can anybody help me through this?

PS: When I change `AVPlayer` to `AVQueuePlayer` it works!

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823411/avplayer-fails-to-play-video-sometimes