# Sending an R2 Video Stream through CloudFlare Workers leads to a crash in Android MediaPlayer and Safari

Tags: video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, cloudflare-workers

Here is the important piece of TS code that trys so find a video-file locate in the [R2-Storage](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/get-started/) from CloudFlare.

```
const { id, ref, hash } = req.param();
if (!await isHashValid(hash))
  return c.text("Unauthorized", 401);

const file: R2ObjectBody = await AR_POSTCARDS.get(`${id}/${ref}`);
if (file === null) return new Response("Object Not Found", { status: 404 });
const headers = new Headers();
file.writeHttpMetadata(headers);
headers.set("etag", file.httpEtag);
headers.set("Content-Type", "video/mp4");

const { readable, writable } = new TransformStream();
file.body?.pipeTo(writable);
return new Response(readable, {
   headers
});
```

The goal is, that an [Android-Mediaplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) can access the worker-url which runs the above code and gets back the video source.

```
  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work out of the box. The Mediaplayer accepts the url, but throws an [error event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)):
response code = 200
W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 3273303 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
I/http: on error: 1  -2147483648

I can't find much information what's going on, so i'll appreciate all help.

Im wondering if there's a part which im missing, for example a valid cors header etc..
Current situation is,

- that the given worker-url runs correct in a chrome browser.
- Safari doesn't play the video and give me an error (Failed to load resource: ...)
- The following curl command also downloads the desired video file correct, which tells me that downloading the file kinda works.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8787/r2/video/{id}/video.mp4/{hash}> test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem:

The problem is, you need to have a partial content response (status code 206).

If you google it, there a some headers you have to set.

In order to fix this issue, you need to extract the range from the request and respond with a 206:

```
  const { id, ref } = c.req.param();

  // get start and end from range header
  const range = c.req.header("Range");
  const startEnd : number[] = range?.replace('bytes=', '')?.split('-')?.map(val => parseInt(val));
  const [start, end] = startEnd ?? [0, 1];

  try {
    const options: R2GetOptions = {
      range: {
        offset: start,
        length: end-start,
      }
    };
    const file: R2ObjectBody = await R2_BUCKET.get(`${id}/${ref}`, options);
    if (file === null) return new Response("Object Not Found", { status: 404 });

    const headers = new Headers();
    file.writeHttpMetadata(headers);
    headers.set("etag", file.httpEtag);
    headers.set("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
    headers.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    headers.set("Content-Range", `bytes ${start ?? 0}-${end ?? 1}/${file.size}`);
    headers.set("Content-Length", `${end - start}`);
    

    return new Response(file.body, {
      headers,
      status: 206,
    });
```

Another usefull link:
[AVPlayer with 206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823411/avplayer-fails-to-play-video-sometimes)